# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sent'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I have this python code when I run it ,it say

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sent'

code:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

packet=scapy.ARP(op=2,pdst="192.168.0.100",hwdst="18:21:95:FA:F4:B9",psrc="192.168.0.1")

scapy.sent(packet)
```

any help will be appreciated, thx

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To encourage other users to help you with your issue, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please make use of the syntax highlighting feature, to increase the readability.

Comment: Er, @jhoepken, they did provide it.  It's a new contributer, just edit the markdown for them?

Comment: Er, @CharlesMerriam sorry about that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `scapy.send` not `scapy.sent`

Typos happen to the best of us. :)